# php - Create canonical/standardised url

Tags: php, url, hyperlink, canonical-link

I have reduced my actual problem to a simple one:

I have some php scripts that display text. E.g.

```
http://example.com/articles.php?id=2
```

could display an article with title `My little cat`.

However, the url is ugly for sharing. How can I implement a system whereby a user types something like `http://example.com/articles/My_little_cat` and be redirected to the same place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by defining RewriteRules in the `.htaccess` file.

```
RewriteRule ^articles/My_little_cat/?$ articles.php?id=2
```